# how to use \insert{_file_} to include tikz \draw command?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using Stata to run some simultions, and my data change every time I run my do file.  My data have a discontinuity that changes with each run and I'd like a curly brace that reflects the size of the discontinuity.  I thought I could do this by having Stata write to file the following info, where the numbers change with every run:

```
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace},thick] (axis cs:0.1,0.846) to
       node[midway,right] (bracket) {0.339}
       (axis cs:0.1,0.507);
```

And then using an \insert{*filename*} command to call that, as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$\hat{\delta}$},
xlabel={$x$},
xmin=-4.5,
xmax=4.5
]
\addplot coordinates {(-4.5,0) (0,.507)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,.8456) (4.5,1)};
\insert{filename};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
               {
l.39 \insert{
         _filename_};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\input` instead of `\insert`.  I'm not sure what `\insert` does, so I don't know why that doesn't work (`\show\insert` helpfully says `\insert=\insert`), but `\input` *does* work so use that.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={$\hat{\delta}$},
xlabel={$x$},
xmin=-4.5,
xmax=4.5
]
\addplot coordinates {(-4.5,0) (0,.507)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,.8456) (4.5,1)};
\input{pgfplotsinsertion};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: inserted file]

Comment: Hmm, image doesn't show for some reason.  I'm pretty sure I uploaded one.

Comment: The image shows now. Sometimes imgur takes a while to process the image.

Comment: According to TeX by Topic (chapter 29), `\insert` adds a floating box (or something like that, seems to be complicated).

Comment: I think I just misread the manual.  mea culpa - thanks for straightening me out!